# Difference between getService().fetchModelName() and getService().getModelName()

Tags: liferay, liferay-service-builder

What's the difference between `getService().fetchModelName()` and `getService().getModelName()`? These methods don't seem to contain any implementation. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Where do you see / use these methods?

Comment: Those are service builder methods used to retrieve data from the database.

Found an answer here:
[link](http://www.marconapolitano.it/en/liferay/22-entitylocalserviceutil-difference-between-getentity-and-fetchentity.html)

Comment: That is what I also know. I mean to ask, in which class do you see these methods?

Comment: Those are found in *ServiceUtil classes